# icalendar "not supported calendar message.ics" issue

Tags: icalendar

My website sends icalendar invitations by email. Everything worked fine until September 2019, when some users started receiving emails with a file attached named "not supported calendar message.ics".

After testing, I found out that the invitations go through correctly, but the cancellations result in the "not supported calendar message.ics" attachments. This result is quite surprising to me; if the invite goes through correctly, why would the cancellation result in a bug?

Here is an example of the invite (works fine):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//My website//Event Invitation
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=AQAJ:MAILTO:noreply@mywebsite.org
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=FALSE;CN=johndoe@gmail.com:MAILTO:johndoe@gmail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=fr-FR:blablablablablablablablablablablabla\n\n
    blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
    blablabla.\n\nblablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
UID:AQAJ962
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=fr-FR:Réunion du Comité Finances
DTSTART:20191127T170000Z
DTEND:20191127T190000Z
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20191125T150330Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=fr-FR:Boul. René-Lévesque Ouest, Montréal (Québec)
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And here is an example of the cancellation (results in an attachment named "not supported calendar message.ics"):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:CANCEL
PRODID:-//My website//Event Invitation
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=AQAJ:MAILTO:noreply@mywebsite.org
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=FALSE;CN=johndoe@gmail.com:MAILTO:johndoe@gmail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=fr-FR:blablablablablablablablablablablabla\n\n
    blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
    blablabla.\n\nblablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
UID:AQAJ962
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=fr-FR:Annulé: Réunion du Comité Finances
DTSTART:20191127T170000Z
DTEND:20191127T190000Z
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:1
DTSTAMP:20191125T145125Z
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:1
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=fr-FR:Boul. René-Lévesque Ouest, Montréal (Québec)
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please shate with us more details. The code from which the email is sent is written in .NET, ruby, java, python or other? The clients are using outlook, office365, lotus, gmail or some other clients?

Comment: @tukan the code is sent in PHP using PHPMailer, client uses office365

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong, but perhaps you are missing one part.

In my eyes, this is similar to reschedule issue where **organizer's email** address does not correspond (is not equal to) to the (cancellation) **FROM** address.

In your cancelation is the **organizer's email = FROM email** address?  If not, you have to make them the same.